# Greensock library morphSVG animation

Tags: animation, gsap

I am trying to make an animation that will fill a tube with liquid and then start moving the liquid inside. I am using an SVG with 3 main paths, the first one is liquid with short height, which then I morph to become the liquid with long height, then I want to "repeat" the morph between the other 2 paths to make it look like the liquid is moving, however when i move from one path to the other using morphSVG, I can't go back to the previous path, so my other morphSVG statement isn't executed.

Here's link to my code:

https://codepen.io/BrittanyR/pen/rJvOyX

As can be seen, I am able to move from one path to the other using:

```
  TweenMax.to("#redSecondary", 2, {morphSVG: "#redPrimary", delay: 2})
```

But I can't then use this: `TweenMax.to("#redPrimary", 2, {morphSVG: "#redSecondary"})`

Any idea will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it was just a logic issue in your code - your setTimeout() was alternating between animating #redPrimary and #redSecondary (targets), but you never changed what they were animating TO. So it worked the first time...and that's it. Every subsequent call was just duplicating the exact same movement (tweening to the current values...thus no motion).

I wonder if this is what you were looking for: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/gvzMLG?editors=0010

Note: as a convenience, MorphSVGPlugin automatically records the original path data for the element so that if you ever want to animate back to it (like to("#redPrimary", 2, {morphSVG:"#redPrimary"}), it knows to grab that. It's all automatic :)

So if you want to repeatedly bounce between those morphs, a simple TimelineMax is probably the easiest way. Get rid of all that setTimeout() stuff and just do this:

```
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1, delay:2});
tl.to("#redPrimary", 2, {morphSVG:"#redSecondary", ease:Power1.easeInOut})
  .to("#redPrimary", 2, {morphSVG:"#redPrimary", ease:Power1.easeInOut});
```

Does that help? I'm not entirely sure that I understood your goal properly with the animation, but hopefully this nudges you in the right direction.

Happy tweening!